# How can i check if a column value is in a table using c#?

Tags: c#

I have a table with a column name "FileName" and my file is Tesfile.txt and there are 10 rows .
Is there a way i can check if any row in the table has the value  Testfile.txt in the column "FileName" ?
I am using something like

```
if ( table.Columns["SourceFile"][0] == "Testfile.txt")
{
   //do whatever
}
```

but can i do it simply with linq ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (table.AsEnumerable().Any(row => "Testfile.txt" == row.Field<String>("SourceFile"))) 
{
    // do whatever
}
```

if you want to do the opposite (`None` instead of `Any`), you can do this

```
if (!table.AsEnumerable().Any(row => "Testfile.txt" == row.Field<String>("SourceFile"))) 
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Or even add [this](https://newbedev.com/linq-not-any-vs-all-don-t) and use `None` directly:

```
public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return !source.Any();
}

public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                 Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return !source.Any(predicate);
}
```

Comment: cant  do a != like the following if !(table.AsEnumerable().Any(row => "Testfile.txt" == row.Field<String>("SourceFile"))) 
{
    // do whatever
}

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem?  Do you want to see if there are not rows with `"Testfile.tx"`?

Comment: You need to place the `!` inside the `(`.  Like so `if (!table...`

Comment: or you can replace `==` with `!=`